# Compiler Error Message: CS0246

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on my site (ASP.NET) at home and everything is fine. But when i update the web to the server its gets me this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClibDAL'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have some methods class (ClibDAL) , when I run the web in Visual Studio everything is working.

the error line:

```
Line 4:  <%@ Import Namespace="ClibDAL" %>
```

my web config:

```xml
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="ClibDAL" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>


</configuration>
```

the ClibDAL.cs is in the folder "App_Code".

the head of ClibDAL class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
namespace ClibDAL
{
  public class ClAccessData : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
```

Comment: did you check if the file gets uploaded?

Comment: yes. the file in the server.

Comment: i didnt found how to change the Build Action Property of the cs

Comment: Right-click a file in the Solution Explorer, choose `Properties` -- there's `Build Action` in the property sheet.